# Python Selenium socket.error

Tags: python, wordpress, sockets, selenium, vps

I have python code that parse some information from a certain webpage, create a WordPress post using these info send it to a WordPress based website. This code works perfectly on my computer. I'm trying to run it automatically on a server. It also works perfectly on the server. I want this code to run nonstop for weeks. My problem is after a certain time, the error below occurs and it stops running;

**socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused**

My code is;

```
def Crawler(mainUrl):
    userN='Username'
    passW='Password'

    phase=1
    while phase<=1:
        week=13
        while week<=18:
            gameCnt=1
            bannedGames = []
            while gameCnt<=16:
                phaseUrl='http://www.eurocupbasketball.com/eurocup/games/results?gamenumber='+str(week)
                group=1
                while group<=8:
                    game=2
                    while game<=3:
                        gameCheck = 0
                        gameProcessed = False
                        while gameCheck < gameCnt:
                            try:
                                if bannedGames[gameCheck][0] == group and bannedGames[gameCheck][1] == game:
                                    gameProcessed = True
                                gameCheck+=1
                            except:
                                gameCheck=gameCnt
                        try:
                            driver = webdriver.Firefox()
                            print phaseUrl
                            driver.get(phaseUrl)
                            if not gameProcessed:
                                path='//*[@id="main-one"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div['+str(group)+']/div['+str(game)+']/a/div[3]/span[3]'

                                if "FINAL" in driver.find_element_by_xpath(path).text:
                                    try:
                                        gamePath='//*[@id="main-one"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div['+str(group)+']/div['+str(game)+']/a'
                                        gameUrl=driver.find_element_by_xpath(gamePath).get_attribute("href")
                                        print gameUrl
                                        gameCode = [group,game]
                                        bannedGames.append(gameCode)
                                        gameProcessed=True
                                        processGame(gameUrl,userN,passW,driver)

                                        if gameProcessed:
                                            gameCnt+=1

                                        time.sleep(120)
                                        driver.close()
                                    except:
                                        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
                                        driver.close()
                                        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
                                else:
                                    print "mac bitmedi",game
                                    driver.close()
                        except:
                            print "Sistem hatasi, browser yeniden baslatiliyor"
                            driver.close()
                        game+=1
                    group+=1
            week+=1
        print "basarili",phase
        phase+=1

def processGame(url,userN,passW,driver):
    #Simplified version
    header = "Post Header"
    postText = "Post Content"

    wp = Client('http://mywebsite.com/xmlrpc.php',userN,passW)

    post = WordPressPost()
    post.title = header.decode('iso-8859-9')
    post.content = postText.decode('iso-8859-9')
    post.id = wp.call(posts.NewPost(post))
    post.terms_names = {
            'post_tag': tags,
            'category': cat,
            }

    post.post_status = 'draft'
    wp.call(posts.EditPost(post.id, post))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url="http://www.eurocupbasketball.com/eurocup/games/results"
    Crawler(url)
```

As you can see, I close and reopen driver after each query, it wasn't like that before, it was simply navigating between pages. Yet, someone suggest me that long term sessions may cause that problem, so I've changed it to this form. I've also searched for *socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused*, and as my understanding there are lots of possible cause for it, however I couldn't find any solution matching my problem. What may cause this problem?